# How does the "ACR Call Recorder" work in Android?

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

```
AudioSource.VoiceCall
AudioSource.VoiceCommunication
AudioSource.VoiceUplink
AudioSource.VoiceDownlink
AudioSource.Mic //(This only records the callers voice. Not the receivers voice)
```

Setting the `MediaRecorder` audio source to none of the above works. Possibly the manufacturer has disabled call recording. But how the apps like ACR recorder work?

Are they using the NDK? I'm trying to build a similar app but ended up with the conclusion that I must use the NDK. Any advice would be highly appreciated.

[Call Recorder - ACR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nll.acr&hl=en)

Comment: Is ACR Recorder working for you?

Comment: Yes. I'm using an LG V30+ unlocked version. None of the above methods work buy somehow ACR is working.

Comment: yes, ACR Recorder uses its lib.so file for recording and encoding.

Comment: @global_warming from where did u find that? can u explain how it works?

Answer (score 0):

This Code will surely help you. :)

```
MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
String pathFileName= Environment.getDataDirectory()+"/data/"+
                                            getActivity().getPackageName()+"/Audio/";
                                    File directory=new File(pathFileName);
                                    if (!directory.exists()){
                                        directory.mkdir();
                                    }
String fileName = "YESAB_AUDIO_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".mp3";
                                                audioFilePath=pathFileName+fileName;
                                                myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                                                myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                                                myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                                                myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(audioFilePath);
                                                try {
                                                    myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
                                                myAudioRecorder.start();
```

Comment: I've tried that as well. Although it works, it only records the callers voice. Not the incoming voice. I edited the question.